# Comando DataRow.Delete() por index de Row não conhecida

Tags: c#, datatable

Para remover o `Row` de uma `dataGridView` usando `DataTable` eu posso usar o comando `DataRow.Delete()` mas, por exemplo, no código abaixo ele exclui uma `Row` já conhecida, e no caso eu preciso remover a `Row` que eu estou selecionando com o clique do mouse na `dataGridView`.

Eu pensei em talvez remover pela `index`, pois cada linha criada possui um `index` (até onde eu entendi), então se na seleção eu conseguir pegar o `index` eu posso excluir a linha do `DataTable` e do `dataGridView`.

Se alguém puder me ajudar a como pegar a `index` da linha selecionada eu agradeço muito.

```
     <//Código exemplo
     for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
        if (dr["name"] == "Joe")
            dr.Delete();
    }>

    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Cadastro");

     <
     //botão para salvar o que eu digitei nas text box (informa o nome e o email do usuario na textbox e mostra no dataGridView)
     private void bt_salvar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Pessoa dados = new Pessoa(txt_nome.Text, txt_email.Text);
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    dr["Nome"] = dados.Nome;
    dr["Email"] = dados.Email;


    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


}>
```

Obs.: Não estou usando banco de dados e a aplicação é em WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `DataGridView` tem a propriedade `CurrentCell` que tem a propriedade `RowIndex`, que retorna o index da linha da célula que está ativa/selecionada.

Para utilizar basta fazer o seguinte:

```
int indexDaLinhaSelecionada = datagridview1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

Comment: Eu acabei conseguindo excluir a linha usando isto:         foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }
    
        dataGridView1.Update();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

Comment: Entendi. Assim funciona também, mas você não acha melhor chamar direto a propriedade ao invés de iterar um laço de repetição?

Comment: Sim, claro. E muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou utilizar essa forma!